# org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Current request is not a multipart request spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

i am trying to upload excel in my project (spring boot) as multipartdata

as follows

**html**

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3">

                                <label for="uploadDocumentMO" class="control-label">Upload Document:</label> 
                                <input type="file" class="filestyle" data-buttonName="btn btn-primary" ng-model="upload.documentMO" id="uploadDocumentMO" name="file" accept="application/xlsx"
                                    base-sixty-four-input>
                            </div>
```

**here is my ajax call**

```
  $("#uploadCorpUserDataBtn").on('click', function() {
        debugger

        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);


            console.log(formData);
            console.log(token);
            $.blockUI({
                message: 'Please wait...',
                css: {
                    border: 'none',
                    backgroundColor: 'white'
                }
            });
            $http.post("http://localhost:8080/api/cmsexcelupload/bulk/corporate/excel/upload/" + username, formData, {
                method: "POST",
                headers: { 'token': token },
            }).then(function(response) {
                console.log(response);
                console.log(response.data.data);
                $scope.merchantData=response.data.data;
                alert("Merchants uploaded successfully");

                $scope.showMerchantData();
                $.unblockUI();
                $scope.userPan = "";
                $scope.upload=null;
            }
});
```

**here is my controller**

```
@PostMapping("/bulk/corporate/excel/upload/{username}") 
    public ResponseEntity<GeneralResponse> merchantbranchUpload( HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response, HttpSession httpSession, @RequestHeader("token") String token ,@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile multipartFile) throws IOException{

corporateExcelUploadLoger.info("Getting Excel from input stream");
        XSSFWorkbook workbook=new XSSFWorkbook(multipartFile.getInputStream());
        String pathTosaveExcelFile=filesUtil.getProperty("documentUploadPath");
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            String excelPath = "D:\\corporateUserExcel_"+dateFormat.format(new Date())+".xlsx";
    }
```

when i hit the server it gives following exception

```
 2020-02-10 15:10:11.419 ERROR 11696 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet]      : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Current request is not a multipart request] with root cause

org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Current request is not a multipart request
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.handleMissingValue(RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.java:190) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:109) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:158) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:128) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at com.apptmyz.fpaeps.utils.SimpleCORSFilter.doFilter(SimpleCORSFilter.java:40) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1457) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_241]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_241]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_241]
```

in spring mvc we will add support we will add multipart support in configuration but in spring boot i did not find any configurations to add.

how to add multipart support  ?

help me with this im very new to spring boot.
thank you.

**edit**

i have added content type but after adding this i get below exception

```
org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileItemIteratorImpl.<init>(FileUploadBase.java:840) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.getItemIterator(FileUploadBase.java:256) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:280) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2863) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParts(Request.java:2772) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParts(RequestFacade.java:1084) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.parseRequest(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:93) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.<init>(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:86) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver.resolveMultipart(StandardServletMultipartResolver.java:79) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.checkMultipart(DispatcherServlet.java:1104) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:936) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at com.apptmyz.fpaeps.utils.SimpleCORSFilter.doFilter(SimpleCORSFilter.java:40) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1457) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_241]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_241]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_241]
```

Comment: Looks like `Content-Type` header is missing from the POST request you are making from front end.

Comment: okay let me give a try

Comment: @YogeshBadke when i add content type it gives `org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found`

Answer (score 2):

In the request header, you should specify the content type, so you should have a header parameter with the name `Content-Type` and the value: `multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------362947062764690924037801`.

EDIT:
I think also you need to configure a multipart resolver in your configuration class, first you add these dependencies in your POM:

```
<!-- multipart resolver-->
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

and you need to declare this `Bean` configuration:

```
@Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
    CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    return multipartResolver;
}
```

Comment: where should i specify this  `boundary=--------------------------362947062764690924037801`

Comment: in the same Content-Type header, like this: "Content-Type=multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------362947062764690924037801"

Comment: Do you have the same exception?

Comment: i did like this ````headers: { 'token': token,'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data;boundary=--------------------------362947062764690924037801' },```` it is giving 400

Comment: Do you have any exception in your Spring application?

Comment: its not hitting controller